# Why Does `-[UILabel setText:]` Leak?

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, uilabel, uiscrollviewdelegate

In a UIScrollViewDelegate class on iOS 4.2.1 in my iPad app, the `-scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` method calls another method that does, this:

```
EntryModel *entry = [entries objectAtIndex:index];
self.titleLabel.text = entry.title;
```

`title` is a nonatomic, retained NSString property of EntryModel. `titleLabel` is a nonatomic, retained property with an IBOutlet connecting it to a UILabel defined in a nib. Following bbum's [blog post](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/), I've been using Heapshot analysis and have identified the above code as a leak. Nearly every time I scroll to a new page, `titleLabel` leaks a bit:

[image]

If I change that second line to:

```
self.titleLabel.text = @"Whatever";
```

The leaking stops:

[image]

I'm confused. Is `-[UILabel text]` not releasing old values before assigning new values? I'm assuming not, that I must be doing something wrong. Why does this leak?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have heapshot generations with zero allocations, it isn't a consistent accretion of memory.  It might be caching [gone wrong] or it might be a leak related to scrolling, something falling through the cracks in the events.

What do the heapshot iterations with allocations in them show?

Comment: Quite a lot of stuff. CGPaths, `<non-object>`s with all kinds of stuff in them.

Comment: could be cache accretion.  could be a genuine leak.  file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're not actually leaking memory.  You *are* allocating memory, as the text property on a UILabel uses copy semantics.  So, calling `self.titleLabel.text` will create a copy of NSString on the right-hand side of the assignment.  Try running with the Leaks instrument to see if you are leaking memory.

Comment: Leaks doesn't see this as a leak, but it clearly is. I understand that `titleLable.text` will create a copy of the NSString on assignment; but why doesn't it release it when a new value is assigned to it (and copied)?

Comment: If Leaks doesn't see it as a leak, why do you think it's a leak?  If `titleLable.text` didn't release the string properly, Leaks would call it a leak.

Comment: Leaks would not call it a leak if the address is still reachable.  That it is still reachable doesn't mean that it isn't also a leak;  abandoned memory is a huge problem (things like write-only caches and the like).   See: http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/